# Shortcut to create/remove desktop in Mac OSX 10.8

Tags: macos, spaces

To switch desktops, one can use < CTRL >-i or < CTRL >-[< left >< right >].  Are there shortcuts to create and remove desktops?  If not, how can I make them?

Comment: Maybe this link can help you [http://stackoverflow.com/q/9606221/1884961](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9606221/1884961)

Answer (score 1):

I would use Automator's watch me function to record the keys and mouse actions needed to add a new screen.

Barring that, you'd need to hack the plist and restart finder or get third party MouseTools to help with UI automation.

See this post for those options:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9606221/